# How to customize Serilog fields in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, .net-core, serilog

I wrote a middleware that I caught errors with Serilog. I want to write the captured errors to the database. The data I want to write includes information such as user name and the name of the relevant controller.

The middleware I wrote is as follows:

```cs
public static class ApiGlobalExceptionHandlerExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseWebApiExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var loggerFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(ILoggerFactory)) as ILoggerFactory;

        return app.UseExceptionHandler(HandleApiException(loggerFactory));
    }

    public static Action<IApplicationBuilder> HandleApiException(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        return appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.Run(async context =>
            {
                var exceptionHandlerFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

                if (exceptionHandlerFeature != null)
                {
                    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Serilog Global exception logger");
                    logger.LogError(500, exceptionHandlerFeature.Error, exceptionHandlerFeature.Error.Message);

                }

                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("An unexpected fault happened. Try again later.");

            });
        };
    }
}
```

As I said in SERILOG SQLServer Sink, the part where I made additional column adjustments on appsettings is this:

```
"columnOptionsSection": {
    "disableTriggers": true,
    "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
    "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
    "addStandardColumns": [
      "LogEvent"
    ],
    "removeStandardColumns": [
      "MessageTemplate",
      "Properties"
    ],
    "additionalColumns": [
      {
        "ColumnName": "EventType",
        "DataType": "int",
        "AllowNull": false
      },
```

I have a way of using it on startup:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                UserManager<AlpIdentityUser> userManager,
                RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
                ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();

    loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Information);
}
```

How can I manage the optional columns I add on this setup?

Comment: What do you mean by "manage the optional columns I add on this setup?" Is something not working as expected? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What I want to do is add a column named username and print the name of the user who encountered the error in this column.

Comment: But I could not find an explanatory example of how to make customizations related to the columns added later. I am using aspnet 2.2. so I can't use the usage styles in the new version.